# Stripe error “Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘result’ of null”

Tags: wordpress, stripe-payments

I'm using [WP Hotel Booking](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-hotel-booking/) with Stripe Payment. Everything is working fine until I reached the checkout.
After Successfully paying with api key correct for testing, payment do not show in the stripe payment dashboard.

Also an error is showing `Stripe error “Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘result’ of null”`.

My Website is wingtons.com

this is a wordpress site and I just used the said plugins so I dont have code to post in here

Comment: Hey there, I would suggest you to write in to Stripe Support, provide more details on your account setting and integration. They could help you from there.

Comment: hI @wsw, yeah already did that. I also post it here cause here, questions got answered quickly. Thank you